# hazelcast management center on docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, hazelcast

i'm using hazelcast with spring boot.

this is hazelcast.xml

```
<hazelcast xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config">
    <cluster-name>hazelcast-test</cluster-name>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="20">5701</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false"/>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member>localhost:5701</member> 
                <member>localhost:5702</member>
                <member>localhost:5703</member>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>

    <management-center scripting-enabled="true" />
</hazelcast>
```

i use three hazelcast server.(5701,5702,5703)

i can see cluster in terminal.

```
Members {size:3, ver:3} [
    Member [localhost]:5701 - eb66e624-3ac7-4524-a915-ebb9fa282515
    Member [localhost]:5702 - 58c38411-3b09-4bb6-8601-33178f00b0c2
    Member [localhost]:5703 - 2e9ffa3e-b061-454d-9402-190911871cd3 this
]
```

after setting cache server, i want to know cache works fine.

so i use docker-comopose to set up management center.

this is docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  management_center:
    image: hazelcast/management-center
    container_name: management-center
    ports:
      - "8443:8080"
    cpus: ".50"  
    mem_limit: "4g"
```

i can see the page of management center at localhost:8443

after i configure the cluster, the error comes out that "Cluster hazelcast-test is disabled. Please, enable it before selecting."

i don't know why it comes out.

i add cluster setting like this on managment-center page(localhost:8443).

```
cluster name : hazelcast-test
Member Addresses : [localhost:5701; localhost:5702; localhost:5701;]
```

please someone help me to connect cluster to management center.

---

i see `<management-center enabled="true">http://localhost:8080</management-center>` to connect hazelcast but now this code is gone.

i'm using these two implementation.

```
implementation 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast:4.2.1'
implementation 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:4.2.1'
```

how to configure management center with spring boot(hazelcast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` isn't going to work with Docker. `localhost` inside a container will not refer to `localhost` outside the container.

Try following [this guide](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/getting-started/get-started-docker), using the latest versions

Comment: thank you to let me know! i forget that fact!